# Dudas al usar XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, fileupload, xmlhttprequest

dentro de unos días tengo pensado programar un file-uploader usando Javascript y php.
Basicamente los unicos archivos que se podran subir seran .zip
Sin embargo, antes de realizar la request, se deberán cumplir una serie de condiciones como:

1. Que contenga una serie de archivos.
2. Que los archivos contengan X contenido.

Bien, hasta aquí todo fácil, **mis dudas son las siguientes**

1. Se puede burlar las condiciones previamente mencionadas? En tal caso, como podría evitarlo?
2. Existe la posibilidad que inyecten código no deseado?

Cualquier consejo es de mucha ayuda, gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones. En cuanto a la pregunta 1: Las condiciones se pueden burlar, en cuanto a cómo evitarlo, se puede escribir una enciclopedia sobre ello. En cuanto a la pregunta 2: La respuesta es sí. Te recomiendo que acotes tu problema, mostrando el código que has intentado.

Comment: @A.Cedano Bueno, el codigo lo hare dentro de unos dias dado que no es nada del otro mundo y hay por internet varios ejemplos sobre ello, sin embargo, el tema del diccionario me interesa. ¿A que te refieres con ello?. Con respecto a las inyecciones de codigo, me preocupa que en unos de los archivos añadan funciones de php como exec, shell_exec...etc Y me gustaria evitar dichas inyecciones de php.

Comment: Hablé de una enciclopedia para decir que hay mil formas de hacer eso, y que debes mostrarnos tú la forma que has elegido entre esas miles. Entonces te ayudaremos con eso en concreto. En programación hay muchas maneras de hacer las cosas, la finalidad del sitio no es decirte cuál usar, sino ayudarte con la que hayas elegido. Debes dar ese primer paso.